# Flutter Dart 2D Array to Widget

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a array. I want to print this array with title header. I tried a lot of things but couldn't find a solution.

```
$marks = array(
"TİTLE 1" => array(
array(
"image" => "https://image.com",
"name" => "AAAA",
"id" => 1111,),
array(
"image" => "https://image.com",
"name" => "AAAA",
"id" => 1111,),
),
"TİTLE 2" => array(
array(
"image" => "https://image.com",
"name" => "AAAA",
"id" => 1111,),
array(
"image" => "https://image.com",
"name" => "AAAA",
"id" => 1111,),
),
);
```

[The output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdmQB.png)

I tried this but i cant print title.

populerplaylist.map((user) => ).toList(),

Comment: What have you tried in flutter? Your code isn't dart.

Comment: @puelo this my array's php code. I use flutter to print this array.

Comment: You will have to put in some effort yourself before anyone is willing to help with a *specific* problem. Nobody will do the whole work for you.

Comment: I've already tried to do that, I came here because I couldn't. What are you doing here if you're not going to help people? Are you the judge? I will report you.
@puelo

Comment: 1. PHP and Dart don't work together unless you are using an API? Are you using an API? How do you get the "Array" into flutter?
2. Your provided dart code doesn't make any sense: what's that variable 'populerplaylist'? Why is there a missing return value `(user) => here`? Where is the print statement? How do you intend to "print" to a widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all your table is in the php language.
If you want to have it or receive it in flutter format it will be of this type:

```json
Map<String, dynamic> marks = {
    "TITLE 1": [
      {
        "image" : "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.vikidia.org%2Fvikidia%2Ffr%2Fimages%2Ff%2Fff%2FChat_gris.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
        "name" : "Cat 1",
        "id" : 1111,
      },
      {
        "image" : "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.vikidia.org%2Fvikidia%2Ffr%2Fimages%2Ff%2Fff%2FChat_gris.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
        "name" : "Cat 2",
        "id" : 1111,
      }
    ],
    "TITLE 2": [
      {
        "image" : "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.vikidia.org%2Fvikidia%2Ffr%2Fimages%2Ff%2Fff%2FChat_gris.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
        "name" : "Cat 1",
        "id" : 1111,
      },
      {
        "image" : "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.vikidia.org%2Fvikidia%2Ffr%2Fimages%2Ff%2Fff%2FChat_gris.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
        "name" : "Cat 2",
        "id" : 1111,
      }
    ]
  };
```

Then if you want to display it in the form you want here is the code that does that:

```dart
 Widget displayMap(){
    List<Widget> list = [];

    marks.forEach(((key, value) {
      List<Widget> listWidgetTmp = [
        Text(key, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
      ];

      listWidgetTmp.add(
        Container(
          height: 150,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: value.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              dynamic mark = value[index];
              
              return Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Image.network(mark["image"], height: 100, width: 100,),
                    Text(mark["name"]),
                  ],
                )
              );
            }
          )
        )
      );

      list.addAll(listWidgetTmp);
    }));

    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: list,
    );
  }
```

So this is the result:
[image]

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Get the data through api. Create a model class of that api response in your flutter project. Use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) or [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package for api parsing. Create function to decode your api response. Show images using `image.network()`